# Dúvida com variável global em um controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Eu possuo um método no meu *controller* que é chamado através do ajax. Ele popula uma variável global dentro desse *controller*.

Existe alguma forma de eu acessar essa variável global já populada pelo primeiro método se eu chamar outro método ajax na mesma página e *controller*?

O objetivo final: Essa variável seria uma lista grande de dados que são gerados randomicamente. Então eu quero no primeiro método gerar. A pessoa vê os dados e se ela der o ok ela volta ao *controller* com esses mesmos dados e faz outra ação com eles.

Comment: Já tentou por em uma TempData ? não entendi certo seu contexto

Comment: Dê mais detalhes do que deseja fazer. Ás vezes, pode ter mais de uma solução para o seu caso. Exemplo: salvar a informação no localStorage do navegador, se usar Angular você pode usar o `$rootScope` (mas a informação se perde no _refresh_ da página), etc

Comment: Fiquei com a msm dúvida quando ele postou, se era angular ou não porém é do lado do server que ele está utilizando e não do client a variavel global.

Comment: Por que você precisa dessa variável global? As vezes o seu erro está na forma como tenta resolver o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível fazer por variável global.

Para cada requisição o *controller* é instanciado, então sua variável global irá perder o valor.

Uma boa prática para fazer isso é através de *Session state* ou *cookies*.

Uma forma de fazer isso como uma gambiarra é tornar sua variável global como `static`, **porém não é recomendado** usar um estado global mutável em uma aplicação web.

Answer (score 1):

Isto é uma baita gambiarra. O que você pode fazer é [instalar o Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/redis-64/) e gravar este "estado" por usuário numa chave fora da aplicação ASP.NET MVC.

O acesso a esta variável é feito [por este *client*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis/).

Comment: Estava procurando exatamente isso . :)